# Creating folder - sub/dir within loop and repeating the same process function loop within its loop and maintaining its previous echoed structure

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to create a sub tree menu and make sure every single directory is being viewed and mapped out.
As you can see I would like the $subbing to repeat the whole process again but as long it is maintaining within its dir path that was previously echoed out

```
$new_array = array("../uploads/rafcastro77/jeff/jeff/portfolio/",
    "../uploads/rafcastro77/one/",
    "../uploads/rafcastro77/three/",
    "../uploads/rafcastro77/two/jeff/jeff/portfolio/");

foreach($new_array as $branch_sub){

    $array = $branch_sub;

    $array = explode('/', $array);

    $subs = '';
    $subbing = '';
    foreach($array as $arrays){     

//collect sql
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE dir='$subbing'");

    $subbing .= $arrays . '/';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $path = $row["path"];
        $file_name = $row["sub_dir"];

             if(empty($file_name)){
             echo "<li>" . $path . "</li>";
             }else{
              echo "<li>" . $file_name . 
             " - repeat this sub $subing with another loop until end</li>";
             }}

            //end collect sql 

    if(!empty($arrays)){echo '<li><span>' . $arrays . '</span><ul>';}}

        foreach($array as $arrays){     
    if(!empty($arrays)){echo '</ul></li>';}         
    }}
```

This is the result I get once a assembled with its css sheet on the picture as you can see I did a little diagram to get an idea of what I need I hope that helps.

I would want it to keep repeating till the is no more directory-subs within folder.
[image]